# PHP: Default SOAP XML Namespace

Tags: php, xml, wcf, soap

I'm using PHP 5.6 as that is what the client is using. I have to communicate with a Microsoft WCF Service via SOAP without using WSDL.

I'm more or less there, however it would make my life a lot easier if there was a way to set the default XML namespace for the SOAP envelope.

I thought setting the 'URI' option on the `SoapClient` constructor would do this but it hasn't.

The WCF service sets this default namespace, so without it, I have to explicitly mark up all the `SoapVar` variables with that namespace in order for it to work.

Is it possible to get the `SoapClient` to set the default namespace?

i.e.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<!-- SOAP Contents -->
</soap:Envelope>
```

Default Namespace being `http://tempuri.org/`.

Comment: Can you show the code how you instantiate the SoapClient?  The $options parameter in the constructor has a uri option that is used to set the namespace in non-wsdl mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking that then you're probably using WSDL mode. The WSDL defines the default namespace.

Otherwise [the docs](http://php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapclient.php) help you:

> If working in non-WSDL mode, the location and uri options must be set, where location is the URL of the SOAP server to send the request to, and uri is the target namespace of the SOAP service.

Comment: Strange, was definitely not using the WSDL mode, and setting the `uri` option had no effect on the default namespace of the soap envelope. The client I am working with is using php 5.4 so that could be a factor